# Is it possible to explicitly omit a parameter when calling the Date() constructor?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to come up with creating a date from a value that can be either a datetime string or a `null` value. When a null value is provided, the date should default to now.

This works, but doesn't really seem elegant:

```
const date = value ? new Date(value) : new Date()
```

It would be more readable to have the expression like this:

```
// Naive example
const date = new Date(value || undefined)
```

The problem is that `new Date(undefined)` is not the same as `new Date()` and it will return `Invalid Date`. Is there a way around this? Maybe somehow explictly not pass a parameter to he constructor?

Comment: You could do `new Date(value || Date.now())`. The advantage is that everyone will understand what date is returned as the "default" case. *"Maybe somehow explictly not pass a parameter to he constructor?"* You could make use of parameter spread: `var args = value ? [value] : []; new Date(...args)`, but I'd argue it's even less clear what's going on here. Having a separate call, like in your first example, or passing `Date.now()` makes it very clear what the purpose of the code is.

Comment: what about `new Date((value || undefined) ? value : null)`

Comment: @ImanEmadi: `new Date(null)` is the same as `new Date(0)`.

Comment: [Huh](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-value), passing `undefined` doesn't work, that's unfortunate

Comment: I would explicitly call out what you are doing (either return a date based on `value` or the current date) so the next developer who reads it doesn't have to think too hard.  Perhaps the ternary non elegant code is best for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
new Date(value || Date.now())
```

The advantage is that everyone will understand what date is returned as the "default" case.

> Maybe somehow explictly not pass a parameter to he constructor?

You could make use of parameter spread:

```
var args = value ? [value] : [];
new Date(...args)
```

but I'd argue it's even less clear what's going on here. Having a separate call, like in your first example, or passing `Date.now()` makes it very clear what the purpose of the code is.